# Apache Lens: Error when starting the server

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, pom.xml

I am trying to start the Apache Lens on my server. I got JDK and the fork HIVE installed like it is required.
When I run the Apache Lens Server (bin/lens-ctl start), I am getting this error in the logs:

```
> SLF4Jption in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService: method <init>()V not found
> path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in
> [jar:file:/home/apps/apache-lens-2.5.0-beta-bin/server/webapp/lens-server/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: Found binding in
> [jar:file:/home/apps/forked-hive/apache-hive-2.1.1-inm-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
> explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
> [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder] Exception in
> thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService: method <init>()V not found
>         at org.apache.lens.server.LensServices.init(LensServices.java:186)
>         at org.apache.lens.server.LensServer.startServices(LensServer.java:134)
>         at org.apache.lens.server.LensServer.<init>(LensServer.java:85)
>         at org.apache.lens.server.LensServer.createLensServer(LensServer.java:74)
>         at org.apache.lens.server.LensServer.main(LensServer.java:190)
```

Does anyone encounter this error before? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have picked hive 2.1.x, lens
release 2.5.0-bin does not work with that yet. Please pick hive 0.13.x for
you to proceed.

See the email thread for details:
https://www.mail-archive.com/user@lens.apache.org/msg00102.html